# How to turn off a particular hard disk in a multiple disk computer system to save power?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, power-management, powersave

Explanation:

I have about 5 hard disks in my windows 7/8 machine. Since, the operating system is only installed in 1 disk, the rest 4 drives just consume power staying connected to the motherboard.

Now, those 4 disks are only used for data storage and backup purposes. So they are seldom used. In this case, is there any way to turnoff power to the hard-disks not being used? Or at least, is there a way to force the hard disks in lower power consumption state?

How to force them to stop drawing power while they are not being used most of the time? Are there any softwares to achieve this?

Comment: You can use the built-in option in windows and see if it works for you (It didn't work for and I had to use AHCI hot-swap feature to connect the backup drive when needed and disconnect it when I finish)

Anyway here's the method:
Control Panel > power options > change plan settings > change advanced power settings > Hard disk , and choose how long to wait before turning 'idle' hard disks off.

Comment: I have that setting turned on set to 10 minutes, but I can hear one hard disk spinning intermittently even if that drive has not been used by any program. My Operating System drive is SSD drive.